# Qt BLE. Can only get notification of one of two characteristic changes in a [custom] service

Tags: qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Nordic nrf communicating with a Qt app running on Linux. The Qt app is set up to get notification of a custom characteristic within a custom service. This works fine.

I have then added a second characteristic to the Nordic custom service.

If I connect my phone to the Nordic I get notifications from both characteristics. However, with my Qt app, I cannot get the second characteristic to work at all.

I am doing this with the first characteristic that works:

```
void MainWindow::setReceiveCharacteristic(CharacteristicInfo *cInfo)
{

    watchedData = cInfo->getCharacteristic(); 

    if (watchedData.isValid())
        {
        const QLowEnergyDescriptor notificationRW = watchedData.descriptor(QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration));            
        currentService->writeDescriptor(notificationRW, QByteArray::fromHex("0100")); 
        }
}
```

Then trying this with the second:

```
void MainWindow::setDataFromNordicCharacteristic(CharacteristicInfo *cInfo)
{

    dataFromNordicCharacteristic = cInfo->getCharacteristic();
    if (dataFromNordicCharacteristic.isValid())
        {
        const QLowEnergyDescriptor dataFromNordicDescriptor = dataFromNordicCharacteristic.descriptor(QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration));   
        currentService->writeDescriptor(dataFromNordicDescriptor, QByteArray::fromHex("0100"));
        if (dataFromNordicDescriptor.isValid())
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Second descriptor is valid");
        else
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Second descriptor is not valid");
        }
}
```

currentService is my custom service.

I added the check for valid descriptor for the second as a sanity check and that's fine. These two functions only get called when the custom service is discovered and specific UUIDs are found in the service.

I then do this:

```
connect(currentService, SIGNAL(characteristicChanged(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)), this, SLOT(newCharacteristicValue(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)));
```

I assume that you only need one connect per service and not per characteristic.

Can anyone see what i might be doing worng please? If you need any more code snippets please ask.

*Edit: I have discovered that the Nordic gets a message in saying that the characteristic has its notification enabled. I have confirmed this is by the:*

```
currentService->writeDescriptor(dataFromNordicDescriptor, QByteArray::fromHex("0100"));
```

*line because if I take this line out I never get the connected signal. So, it seems like something is sending a disconnect signal, however, I can see no mechanism within the Qt code that would do that.*

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier create **two separate custom services** on the peripheral (Nordic nrf). Each service contains a characteristic for the data and a descriptor with `ClientCharacteristicConfiguration` to enable notifications from the central device (Qt app).

In your Qt App you have to connect to both services and enable notification by writing the descriptor as you did. In your slot `newCharacteristicValue(QLowEnergyCharacteristic,QByteArray)` you can distinguish between  characteristics by their uuid.

If you need an example use Qt heartrate-game example.